# Form hangs when App Connects to Internet

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Form Application. It detects the Network dynamically. Means Whenever Internet is available it will go to connect and when it is not available it will begin working in offline mode. The problem is when the app detects the Internet and goes to connect to Internet, I cannot move the app on screen by mouse. After it connects to network(around 20 seconds) it will be movable. I want to move the form even when it is connecting to Internet.

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread.  Create another thread to do whatever long running operations you have to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Show a Sand Clock ( Processing Symbol in Mouse Cursor )  While it connects to Internet  . if you want to make while it connects put form object in separate thread

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect network connectivity on a dedicated thread.  Checking on the main (UI) thread blocks it until the check is done, which is why the UI locks up.

See "A Non-Responsive UI" in this [Visual Studio Magazine article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx), but online resources for how to do this abound.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I think you need to use threads. Look up [background worker on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Your app runs in a main thread and if you fire off another process which can take a long time your main thread waits i.e. hangs.